# Setting POST request from iOS (Notice: Undefined Index)

Tags: php, ios, post, webserver

I have been ready every possible post about issues related to the php Notice: Undefined Index but none of the solutions have worked for me. Please help me solve this problem.

I am sending a POST request from iOS to php. When I try to access &_POST['field1'], I get Notice: Undefined Index field1.

Most other people solve their problem by adding if(isset($_POST['field1']), by suppressing the warning using error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE) or changing their quotes.

In my case, when I add the if statement isset, I do not meet the condition and skip over the part where I access field1. I am assuming this has to do with how I am setting my request in iOS. This has been the method I use;

```
   NSString *content = @"field1=hello&field2=world";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/www/service.php/"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```